# Write log message depending on the git branch?

Tags: python-3.x, git

Can you have certain information written into a log file in a Python program, depending on the branch being executed? I was thinking of something like #if DEBUG or something like that?

```
def log_error(message, args, kwargs):

if not master branch:
  #add further log-information for development branches 
  message = "{} - {} at line {}: {}".format(*self.__calle(), message)

logger.error(message, args, kwargs)
```

Is there a concept for such use cases?

Or do the git sources for the branches have to be different and you always have to pay attention to do a merge from dev to master?

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the existing log levels and names to deal with this. Managing different code in different branches is extremely error prone, and using the git branch doesn't always make sense (what branch are you "on" in a production environment?)

Comment: I see it similarly, I don't want to have to manage branches with different code either. 
Do you have an idea how to log errors in a development branch differently than in the release branch? 
I wrote my post with the exact name of the method used to log errors.

Comment: You have different *config* for the different environments, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging. Also note you shouldn't format the log string yourself, it's more efficient to let the logger do it *if* that log is being handled.